# RequireJS Error - require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){return Z}

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend

I'm new to RequireJS and trying to figure out why this is happening. I have a custom file stickyNav.js in `<vendor>/<theme>`/web/js.

I've added a requirejs-config.js file in `<vendor>/<theme>`/web/.

```
var config = {
     map: {
         '*' : {
             'stickyNav': 'js/stickyNav'
         }
     }
 };
```

This is my js code (to call console.log as a test)

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'stickyNav'], function($, stickyNav){
        console.log('Working');
    }
 );
```

Obviously I have this wrong. I read the official doc's, but i'm still struggling.

Comment: We want to see your stickyNav.js, maybe the problem is inside

Answer (score 1):

correct code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'stickyNav',
    'jquery/ui'
], function ($, stickyNav) {
    console.log('Working');
});
```